# How to access kth element in a c++ std::set in logarithmic time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a list of numbers in which I need to support multiple queries of two types: either I can delete an element or I need to find kth smallest(k can be different in each query) element in the remaining list.

Since both of these can be supported in logarithmic time if I use a self balancing BST, and since `std::set` is implemented over self balancing BSTs, there should be an API for accessing kth element in logarithmic time using it. If there isn't such a method:

i) Why? This seems like a frequent use case to me.

ii) Is implementing self balancing trees my only hope or can I make it work using something else?

Comment: That `std::set` is commonly implemented using a tree is an implementation detail. The C++ standard only specifies the container *interface* not the implementation. If you explicitly need a tree structure you should implement it yourself.

Comment: How can you access the k-th smallest element in a plain BST (without storing sizes of subtrees) in logarithmic time?

Comment: `std::set` and other associative containers are often implemented using red-black trees, which don't typically know the size of each subtree, only upper and lower bounds on the maximum depth of each subtree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use policy based data structure.

```
To delete you can use : erase(T elementToerase)
To find the kth element : find_by_order(int k) where k is 0 based indexing
                          it returns iterator to kth element.
```

Both the operations are O(logn)

for more details : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/policy_data_structures_design.html

Answer (score 0):

> self balancing BSTs, there should be an API for accessing kth element in logarithmic time using it
>
> I) why [not]?

There does not exist an algorithm for finding nth element in a plain balanced bst in logarithmic time as far as I know.

It might help you to know that a balanced bst can be augmented to achieve the logarithmic operation. The name of such augmented tree is "order statistic tree".

> ii) Is implementing self balancing trees my only hope or can I make it work using something else?

It's not the only option. As always, you can use an existing implementation.

Comment: I think I misremembered. It's only an approximation of the order statistic. .Sorry